# ActiveRecord validate uniqueness against subset of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a `Contact` model that has an `email` attribute. `Contact` `belongs_to :company` and `Company` `has_many :contacts`. I would like to add a uniqueness validation on `Contact` that ensures that the `email` address is unique within the subset of `Contacts` that belong to a given `Company`. In other words, `ABC-Corp` cannot have more than one `Contact` with email `foo.bar@example.com`, however both `ABC-Corp` and `Demo-Corp` can have an contact with the email `foo.bar@example.com`.

I think I need to use the `scope` argument for the `validates_uniqueness_of` method, however I'm not 100% sure if that's what I want as the docs don't do the best job of explaining its usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have to use the `scope` option for this. In your `contact` model, add the below code

```
#contact.rb

validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: :company_id
```

You also need to add an `unique index` to the `contacts` table like below for the sake of **concurrency and integrity**.

```
add_index(:contacts, [:email, :company_id], unique: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let use this:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Your code
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: [:company_id]
end
```

So above code just makes sure the email is unique for each company